# PHP list() expects numerical indexes in v7.4.6

Tags: php, arrays, php-7

In the PHP manual, I read:

> Before PHP 7.1.0, list() only worked on numerical arrays and assumes the numerical indices start at 0.

My code:

```
echo 'Current PHP version: ' . phpversion() . "\n" ;
print_r( $Item ) ;
list( $Cost, $Quantity, $TotalCost ) = $Item ;
```

Output:

```
Current PHP version: 7.4.6
Array
(
    [cost] => 45800
    [quantity] => 500
    [total_cost] => 22900000
)
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in D:\OneDrive\work\Torn\pm.php on line 27

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in D:\OneDrive\work\Torn\pm.php on line 27
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in D:\OneDrive\work\Torn\pm.php on line 27

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in D:\OneDrive\work\Torn\pm.php on line 27
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 2 in D:\OneDrive\work\Torn\pm.php on line 27

Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in D:\OneDrive\work\Torn\pm.php on line 27
```

It seems to me that this version of PHP expects that the indexes are numerical, even if v7.4.6 should be greater than v7.1.0.
Am I missing something?

Comment: You should continue to read further down in the manual how to work with keyed arrays…

Answer (score 2):

```
$Item = [
    'cost'       => 45800,
    'quantity'   => 500,
    'total_cost' => 22900000,
];

[ 'cost' => $cost, 'quantity' => $quantity, 'total_cost'  => $totalCost ] = $Item;
```

Comment: That has been available since PHP 7.1.

Comment: No offence, but this is in the manual: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php. @deceze pointed it out in his comment below the OP...

Answer (score 1):

`list()` does not work with associative arrays, because `list()` wait for an array with numeric keys.

You could use `array_values($Item)`:

```
$Item=[
    'cost'       => 45800,
    'quantity'   => 500,
    'total_cost' => 22900000,
];

list($Cost, $Quantity, $TotalCost) = array_values($Item);

// or equivalent, with array destructuring:
[$Cost, $Quantity, $TotalCost] = array_values($Item);
```

Comment: As of PHP 7.1 associative arrays work.